# Gradle sync failed - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

The gradle sync in Android Studio is failing. This message appears:

> Gradle sync failed: Cannot find JAR 'gson-2.8.5.jar' required by
>   module 'gradle-dependency-management'

What can I do?

Comment: Anybody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382865/upgrading-gradle-5-3-1-to-6-5-older-version-downloaded-dependency-ok-but-fails) it might give you some clues. If gradle fails, and on windows, i usually navigate to `C:\Users\USER\.gradle\wrapper\dists` , on other systems maybe look for the root gradle folder, and delete the gradle version thats bringing me issues and then invalidate cache and sync my project.  No time to waste on gradle.

Comment: I deleted everything in the folder and did a new build. It now has only gradle-6.5-bin. But I am still seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the gradle cache from `C:\Users\USER\.gradle\cache`
Or any other such gradle folder and build the project again.

Whenever there is error with gradle build, I do this and it works for me. I hope it works for you too :)