# Upgrading Gradle 5.3.1 to 6.5. Older version downloaded dependency OK, but fails on 6.5

Tags: gradle, download, dependencies

I have whittled down my problem to a very simple project that declares a module dependency on a module artifact served from my client's artifactory instance.
This is working fine with 5.3.1. As can be seen from the logs below there is a line which indicates DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver  is loading the associated
.jar for this dependency from my maven2 repo  (see: {{{ A }}})

However, when I attempted to upgrade to Gradle 6.5, I get the message

```
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in resolver cache 'maven2'
```

(see {{{ B }}}).

I am too much of a Gradle lightweight to start diving into the source code. I was hoping someone might give me a hint as to what might be the cause of this problem.

Here are the build files (edited for client anonymity):

root project build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
}


subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'

  repositories {
    ['animals'].each { repo ->
      maven {
        name repo
        url "${urlDefinedInGradleProperties}/${repo}"
        credentials {
          username = 'mouse'
          password = 'mouse.mouse'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sub project build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  testCompile group: 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe', name: 'lib-reptile-generator', version: '0.1-806-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Logs are shown below.
Thanks in advance !
/chris

```
Gradle 5.3.1 selected log statements:   No issue downloaded dependency with older version.

22:48:01.145 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Attempting to resolve component for com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT using repositories [maven, maven2, MavenLocal, maven3, iad-lib, toro-ext, iad-lib-ext, gradle-plugins]
22:48:01.146 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in resolver cache 'maven'
22:48:01.146 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Found cached version of changing module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in 'maven2'
22:48:01.146 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Using cached module metadata for module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in 'maven2'
22:48:01.146 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/Users/christopher.bedford/.m2/repository/com/mouse/ap/data/qe/lib-reptile-generator/0.1-806-SNAPSHOT/lib-reptile-generator-0.1-806-SNAPSHOT.pom    {{{ A }}}
22:48:01.146 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/Users/christopher.bedford/.m2/repository/com/mouse/ap/data/qe/lib-reptile-generator/0.1-806-SNAPSHOT/lib-reptile-generator-0.1-806-SNAPSHOT.jar
        ...
22:48:01.146 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in repository 'MavenLocal'.
22:48:01.146 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.PersistentModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT [changing = false]
22:48:01.147 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in resolver cache 'maven3'
22:48:01.147 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in resolver cache 'foo-repo-lib'
22:48:01.148 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Found cached version of changing module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in 'bar-repo-ext'
22:48:01.148 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Using cached module metadata for module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in 'bar-repo-ext'
22:48:01.148 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in resolver cache 'foo-rep-lib-ext'
22:48:01.148 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in resolver cache 'gradle-plugins'
        ...
22:48:01.148 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Using com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT from Maven repository 'maven2'
        ...
22:48:01.149 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.ComponentAttributeMatcher] Selected matches [com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT configuration compile] from candidates [com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT configuration compile, com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT configuration runtime, com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT configuration platform-compile, com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT configuration platform-runtime, com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT configuration enforced-platform-compile, com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT configuration enforced-platform-runtime] for {org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.usage=java-api}
        ...
22:48:01.149 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting configuration com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT(compile).
        ...
22:48:01.150 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of :lib-aci-kafka:testCompileClasspath'
22:48:01.150 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of :lib-aci-kafka:testCompileClasspath' completed
        ...
22:48:01.150 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.ComponentAttributeMatcher] Selected match com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT configuration compile from candidates [com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT configuration compile] for {org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.usage=java-api}
        ...
22:48:01.151 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve lib-reptile-generator.jar (com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT)' started
22:48:01.151 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Found artifact 'lib-reptile-generator.jar (com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT)' in resolver cache: /Users/christopher.bedford/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mouse.ap.data.qe/lib-reptile-generator/0.1-806-SNAPSHOT/68ee2c19e31d164860a270837701cf49e6a76168/lib-reptile-generator-0.1-806-SNAPSHOT.jar
        ...
22:48:01.151 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Resolve lib-reptile-generator.jar (com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT)'
22:48:01.151 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve lib-reptile-generator.jar (com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT)' completed





Gradle 6.5 selected log statements:   Unable to download dependency with latest version.

2020-06-14T22:58:15.997-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.NodeState] dependency: com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT from-conf: testCompile to-conf: null is filtered.
    ...
2020-06-14T22:58:16.071-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Attempting to resolve component for com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT using repositories [maven, maven2, MavenLocal, maven3,  gradle-plugins]

2020-06-14T22:58:16.071-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in resolver cache 'maven'
2020-06-14T22:58:16.071-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in resolver cache 'maven2'  {{{ B }}}
2020-06-14T22:58:16.072-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/Users/christopher.bedford/.m2/repository/com/mouse/ap/data/qe/lib-reptile-generator/0.1-806-SNAPSHOT/lib-reptile-generator-0.1-806-SNAPSHOT.pom
2020-06-14T22:58:16.073-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in repository 'MavenLocal'.
2020-06-14T22:58:16.073-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.PersistentModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT [changing = false]
2020-06-14T22:58:16.073-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in resolver cache 'maven3'
2020-06-14T22:58:16.073-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'com.mouse.ap.data.qe:lib-reptile-generator:0.1-806-SNAPSHOT' in resolver cache 'gradle-plugins'
2020-06-14T22:58:16.073-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://artifacts.mouse.com/libs-release/com/mouse/ap/data/qe/lib-reptile-generator/0.1-806-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
2020-06-14T22:58:16.074-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Opening cache resource-at-url.bin (/Users/christopher.bedford/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.96/resource-at-url.bin)
2020-06-14T22:58:16.076-0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Download https://artifacts.mouse.com/libs-release/com/mouse/ap/data/qe/lib-reptile-generator/0.1-806-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml' started
```

IMPORTANT FOOTNOTE:  If you follow the good advice given in the accepted answer, make sure you avoid my foolish mistake:  Don't put the recommended 'metadataSources' block under  *buildscript { repositories*     That is surely not what you want !

Comment: What artifacts of this particular dependency are stored in the remote repository, is it `pom` + `jar` or maybe only `jar`?

Comment: Hmm interesting question. I checked. there is no metadata of any kind (no pom, etc), just the .jar.. maybe that is the issue ?  I would hate to have to change all upstream build jobs that have not been upgraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment

> there is no metadata of any kind (no pom, etc), just the .jar

your repository contains the `jar` file only and misses the metadata `pom` file. Before 6.0, Gradle tried to derive metadata from `pom` first and then the artifact if `pom` was missing. This changed with Gradle 6. For efficiency reasons, the default metadata sources are `gradleMetadata()` and `mavenPom()` only. So if both are missing Gradle doesn't seem to try to download the `jar`.

To restore the old behavior and being able to resolve the dependency add `artifact()` to your Maven repository `metadataSources` configuration.

```
repositories {
    ['animals'].each { repo ->
        maven {
            name repo
            url "${urlDefinedInGradleProperties}/${repo}"
            credentials {
                username = 'mouse'
                password = 'mouse.mouse'
            }

            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about this in the docs [Supported metadata sources](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:supported_metadata_sources).

Comment: Pretty much spot on answer!  Thanks ;^)